# Apple IAP, multiple non-consumables

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

I'm working on an app where you can create an event. Like a wedding, gig, ... . You can upload content and when you're ready you can click "Create Movie". You go through a payment flow where you buy the product from the Apple IAP.

Now here is the problem. Let's just say, you got a wedding and bought a video for it. You paid, you're happy. A couple months later you have a festival where you want to buy a video for. So you create the event, upload the content, you go to the payment and Apple now just says: You already own this product. Here have it for free. How do I solve this? So this non-consumable has to be individual for every individual event.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "So this non-consumable has to be individual for every individual event." So this non-consumable is consumable.

Comment: According to the Apple employee I talked to it's a non-consumable

Comment: And what was the Apple employee's solution to the question you are now asking?

Comment: Nope, he just complained that we didn't offer this product in the app store but we do on our website so they block updates until we add it. Love Apple. This passive aggressive/toxic tone btw is not helping anyone. What do you suggest? I'm just thinking doing consumables and "consuming" them instantly. Or is that a bad idea

Comment: You could create a consumable IAP that can be redeemed to create a movie. Alternatively you can create a bunch of non-consumable IAPs, all the same price. When you buy the first movie you buy "iap1". When the user goes to purchase again you sell them "iap2" and so on. Eventually they will run out of products to purchase but you could have thousands. You would handle this behind the scenes, so the end user would only ever see the one product in your in App Store, but it would really be different product identifiers

Comment: Right, I think I'm going to go for the consumable IAP. That seems to be the clean option. Thanks for the info!

Comment: Create a consumable 'token' IAP.  The user exchanges a token for a video (or whatever your product is).  The user can purchase multiple tokens - hence multiple videos.  Explain in App Review Notes that you have done this as a 'consumable' so that the user can make multiple purchases BUT you are handling the restore function so the purchase is actually 'non-consumable'.  Use the user's iCloud account to record the user's purchases (and maybe also that video?) and allow them to restore to their other devices.